# Android Mockito test cases with Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, mockito, testcase

I am new to test cases and I am trying to write test cases for the below code but I did not get success after trying several method. My main target is to cover code coverage of MaintenanceStatusResponseHandler.kt class. I am using mockito to write the test cases. I am already implemented jococo for code coverage but I am facing some issue to write a test cases. Please help me to write test cases of MaintenanceStatusResponseHandler class

Thanks in advance

```
    internal class MaintenanceStatusResponseHandler {

    public fun getMaintenanceResponse(voiceAiConfig : VoiceAiConfig):MaintenanceStatus{
        
        val maintenanceStatus = MaintenanceStatus()
        val retrofitRepository = RetrofitRepository()
        val maintenanceUrl : String
        val jwtToken : String

            when (voiceAiConfig.server) {
                BuildConfig.ENV_PRODUCTION_SERVER -> {
                    jwtToken = BuildConfig.JWT_TOKEN_PRODUCTION
                    maintenanceUrl = BuildConfig.MAINTENANCE_PROD_URL
                }
                BuildConfig.ENV_STAGING_SERVER -> {
                    jwtToken = BuildConfig.JWT_TOKEN_STAGING
                    maintenanceUrl = BuildConfig.MAINTENANCE_SANDBOX_URL
                }
                else -> {
                    jwtToken = BuildConfig.JWT_TOKEN_SANDBOX
                    maintenanceUrl = BuildConfig.MAINTENANCE_SANDBOX_URL
                }
            }

        val header = "${VoiceAISDKConstant.JWT_TOKEN_PREFIX} $jwtToken"

        retrofitRepository.getRetrofit(maintenanceUrl)
            .getMaintenanceStatus(header)
            .subscribe { response: MaintenanceStatus.Content, error: Throwable? ->
                error.let {
                    if (error != null) {
                        maintenanceStatus.error = error
                    }
                }
                response.let {
                   maintenanceStatus.content = response
                }
            }
       return maintenanceStatus
    }
}
```

repository class

```
 class RetrofitRepository() {
    val TAG = RetrofitRepository::class.java.canonicalName

    fun getRetrofit(baseUrl: String?): VoiceAiServices {
      val voiceAiServices: VoiceAiServices =  Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl!!)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build().create(VoiceAiServices::class.java)

        return voiceAiServices
    }
}
```

interface

```
interface VoiceAiServices {
@GET("/v1/api/status")
fun getMaintenanceStatus(@Header("Authorization")header: String): Single<MaintenanceStatus.Content>
```

}

Pojo class

```
 data class MaintenanceStatus(
    var error: Throwable? = null,
    var content: Content? = null
) {
    data class Content(
        val enabled: Boolean,
        val maintenanceMsg: String
    )
}
```

Comment: what's your question ?

Comment: `val maintenanceStatus = MaintenanceStatus()` usually having private variables that you depend on won't make testing very easy, you should perhaps consider passing through all dependencies as part of the constructor because, as it stands, how are you going to mock this out ?